# javascript testing using sinon.js & Qunit. how to test for window.location.href and avoid downloading

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, qunit, window.location, sinon

The function is in coffee script:

```
downloadCSVData: ->
      @interval = $('#line_interval').val()
      csv_data_path = "/api/As/" + "&interval=" + @interval
      window.location.href = csv_data_path
```

I need to test this function. I don't know how to check the last line of code. Whenever I call this function, it downloads a file...... I wonder if there's a way I can call the function without downloading the csv file, and I can test if the window.location.href is set to csv_data_path

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trust that `window.location` will do it's thing properly - if it doesn't you have bigger issues. So, just extract the preceding code into a function, and test that:

```
getCSVURL: ->
  @interval = $('#line_interval').val()
  "/api/As/" + "&interval=" + @interval

downloadCSVData: ->
  window.location.href = getCSVURL.call @
```